# Want to parse a string in list and use

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have a list of string. I need to parse it and then use it for further calculations. My

This is the list.

```
list=["3x+3y+2","1x-1y+0","1x+0y-3","0x+1y-0.5"]
```

I tried parsing the list to extract the coefficient of x and y

```
for i in lines:
    re('x,+,y,',i)
```

I want output as

```
[3,3,2],[1,-1,0]
```

etc.
This code is giving me an output as

```
['3x+3y+2']
['1x-1y+0']
['1x+0y-3']
['0x+1y-0.5']
```

Can anybody help me with a hint how to do it?

Comment: What is `regex`? Why did you *expect* a different output from it?

Comment: how works `regex()` ? Show its code.

Comment: maybe see [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) for symbolic mathematics.

Comment: Sorry typo.. not regex..its re..i have edited

Comment: I was trying to split the string with multiple delimiters

Comment: you have to assign result from `re` to variable. Instead of few lines better show minimal working code so we could run it. Now we have to ask for code which  you didnd't show.

Comment: Will there always be three terms?

Comment: `re()` gives error. Show your real code and don't waste our time. To split it you would have to use `result = re.split('[x+y]', i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import re
lst = ["3x+3y+2","1x-1y+0","1x+0y-3","0x+1y-0.5"]
nums_only = [re.findall(r'-?[0-9.]+', elem) for elem in lst]
# [['3', '3', '2'], ['1', '-1', '0'], ['1', '0', '-3'], ['0', '1', '-0.5']]
```

It just uses `re.findall()` to get all occurrences, in order, of the very simple regex `r'-?[0-9.]+'`, in each string. That being, of course, any contiguous sequence of digits or decimal places at least one character long, optionally preceded by a minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the digits(with sign)

```
import re
[re.findall("\-{0,}\d{1,}",i)for i in lis]
```